# Formatting a price with FastReport

Tags: fastreport

I have a problem formatting a price with FastReport, I use the "Format".

This is the statement:
MemoPrice.Text := vartostr(Format('%2.2m', [myPrice]));

The layout works everywhere except in Switzerland where I still see the "€" currency symbol (in USA and UK I see the local currency correctly)

The Windows settings it is correctly set to Switzerland so I don't understand how to fix

Comment: What is "FastReport"? Is software? It is also beneficial if we see his output.

Comment: Not very clear, is the currency OK when printed in Delphi ?